# curl to php to post a json and audio

Tags: php, json, curl

I'm trying to convert a curl command to be used in a php script

```
   curl -k -F "request={'timezone':'America/New_York','lang':'en'};type=application/json" -F "voiceData=@d8696c304d09eb1.wav;type=audio/wav" -H "Authorization: Bearer x" -H "ocp-apim-subscription-key:x" "http://example.com"
```

and here is my php script

```
<?
$data = array("timezone" => "America/New_York", "lang" => "en", "voiceData" => "d8696c304d09eb1.wav");                                                                    
$data_string = json_encode($data);                                                                                   
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer x',
   'ocp-apim-subscription-key:x')
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

I understand that the send audio file bit is not right but i cant find an example how to post it.

I have edited this in response to the post fields but if I include $ch i get no output if don't include the output complains that no post request. Any ideas?

```
<?
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$ch = curl_init('https://example.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
  'Content-type: application/json',
   'Authorization: Bearer x',
   'ocp-apim-subscription-key:x')
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    array('request' => json_encode(array('timezone' => 'America/New_York', 'lang' => 'en')),
          'voicedata' => new CURLFile("d8696c304d09eb1.wav")
    )
);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
echo $result;
?>
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I'd give this a try: `$data = array("request" => json_encode(array("timezone" => "America/New_York", "lang" => "en")) . ";type=application/json", "voiceData" => "@d8696c304d09eb1.wav;type=audio/wav");`  Then remove the `$data_string` line and just use `$data` in the `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` line

Comment: Thanks so much for replying!  I have the data sending now which is a plus but I'm getting a json phase error so will have to keep looking at the issue, do you know if the Voice Data has to been relative to it place on the server

Comment: The file path needs to be the full path, not relative to where the script is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `request=` in your POST fields. Also, sending files using `@filename` is deprecated, you should use the `CURLFile` class.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 
    array('request' => json_encode(array('timezone' => 'America/New_York', 'lang' => 'en')),
          'voicedata' => new CURLFile("d8696c304d09eb1.wav")
    )
);
```

Comment: With the curl_setopt it expects 3 missing the $ch but i draw a blank with it in and without as it is doesn't post.  Warning: curl_setopt() expects exactly 3 parameters, 2 given in